# Symfony same webservice working on Databases

Tags: database, web-services, symfony1, environment

Here is the issue:

I have some methods in action in a Symfony project that are defined in WSDL.
I need a configuration where my ws can work on one of two data bases according to environment.
I tried defining different environments and even different applications.But they all insist to use the DB from the databases.yml under the config on the level of apps.

I really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

In order to select the database connections dynamically you can use the same technique demonstrated in this slide

http://www.slideshare.net/kriswallsmith/symfony-in-the-cloud